# How to capture form input using Selenium WebDriver and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Generally when there's an already existing credential like username, we use:

`driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("Rick")`

But, what if there's an input that the user enters in the form. How to capture that input using JavaScript? I mean, instead of "Rick", I want to capture whatever the user enters and then send that to the `sendKeys()` method.

Comment: you can use `element.getAttribute("value")`  to capture the value of the input element and then you can enter the same using sendkeys